Why $C(g)$ is a representation of $G$?
I'm trying to study on some lecture notes about $G-$structures of Crainic, but I don't understand the following remark:

We will encounter several quite complicated
vector bundles associated to a $G-$structure $S$. However, while the "complicated"
part comes from the linear algebra behind them, the passing to vector bundles
is very simple and rather general. Here is the general discussion that separates the
two steps.
The starting point is the linear context consisting of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a linear subspace $\mathfrak{g}\subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$.


Assume that to such a data we associate some new vector space $C(\mathfrak{g})$ (well, to be
more precise we should really use the notation $C(\mathfrak{g}, V )$. Moreover, we also assume
that $C$ is functorial with respect to the obvious notion of isomorphisms between such
pairs. It follows that when $\mathfrak{g}\subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ arises from a Lie group $G\subset GL(V)$, then $C(\mathfrak{g})$
is a representation of $G$ (as action of $G$ on $( \mathfrak{g},V )$, one just uses the adjoint action
on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the linear action on $V$ ).

I don't understand why it follows that $C(\mathfrak{g})$ is a representation of $G$.

the adjoint action on g - what is "$g$" in your notation for $C(g)$? We also have the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, but this is a different notation.

@DietrichBurde you are right the notation is wrong, g should be $\mathfrak{g}$. I edited the question, thanks.

I'll try to state more explicitely what the author is trying to say. Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the category (a groupoid to be more precise) constructed as follows:

The objects are the couples $(\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{V})$ where $\frak{g}$ is a Lie sub-algebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbf{V})$ and $\mathbf{V}$ is a real vector space.

A morphism $(\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathbf{V}_1)\to (\mathfrak{g}_2,\mathbf{V}_2)$ is a couple $(f:\mathfrak{g}_1\to \mathfrak{g}_2,F:\mathbf{V}_1\to \mathbf{V}_2)$, where $f$ is a Lie algebras isomorphism and $F$ is a linear isomorphism.

The composition of morphism is the entry-wise one.


Let's suppose we have a functor $$C:\mathscr{G}\to \textbf{Vect}_\mathbb{R},$$ where $\textbf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ is the category of finite-dimensional real vector spaces with linear maps.
Let $G\subseteq \text{GL}(\mathbf{V})$ be a Lie group and let $\mathfrak{g}\subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbf{V})$ be its Lie algebra. We can construct a representation of $G$ in $C(\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{V})$ as follows
$$G\to \text{GL}(C(\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{V})),\ \ \ g\mapsto C(\text{Ad}_g,g),$$
where $C(\text{Ad}_g,g)$ is the previously constructed functor evaluated on the morphism $$(\text{Ad}_g,g):(\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{V})\to (\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{V}).$$
Recall that $\text{Ad}_g$ is the differential (in the identity) of the diffeomorphism $G\to G,\ h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$.
